# Bilinear Transformation in Audio EQ Cookbook

Tags: filter-design, bilinear-transform

In the [Audio EQ CookBook](https://webaudio.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt) there is $$\omega_0 = 2\pi\cdot\frac{f_0}{f_s}$$so  frequency warping will be $$\omega_r = \frac{2}{T}\tan(\frac{\omega_0}{2})$$

Then $$s \longleftarrow \frac{2}{T}\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}} = \frac{\omega_r}{\tan\frac{\omega_0}{2}}\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}}$$
But in the in the CookBook, we're given:
$$s \longleftarrow \frac{1}{\tan\frac{\omega_0}{2}}\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}}$$

What does $\omega_0 = 2\pi\cdot\frac{f_0}{f_s}$ exactly mean?

Comment: Robert Bristow-Johnson is a major contributor on this website and can probably answer your question. As far as $\omega_0$, it is the normalized frequency in radians/sample. See [this Dan Boschen answer on the subject](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/41520/63763)

Comment: @RobertBristow-Johnson (I think that alerts Robert to the question, not sure)

Comment: @DanBoschen Users are only notified of `@` if they comment on the same post

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Got it. Well I doubt he would miss the title “Audio EQ Cookbook”.